# DoctrineExtensions - How to translate a slug?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-extensions

I've been working the past 2 hours on translating my slug without much success. First, let's take a look at my entity :

```
/**
 * BlogPost
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BlogPost implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(length=128)
     */
    private $slug;
```

It's pretty straightforward. Now, when I do :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$blogPost = new BlogPost();
$blogPost->setTitle('my title in FRANCAIS');
$blogPost->setTranslatableLocale('fr_ca');
$em->persist($blogPost);
$em->flush();

$blogPost->setTitle('my title in ENGLISH');
$blogPost->setTranslatableLocale('en_us');
$em->persist($blogPost);
$em->flush();
```

Only my title gets translated, but my slug is only in french. [I tried that solution from the doc](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md#using-translationlistener-to-translate-our-slug) ... but there is no TranslationListener (the file does not exist). There is only one note in the doc that doesn't mean much to me :

> Note: these translations will not be processed as ordinary fields of your object, in case if you translate a slug additional translation will not know how to generate the slug, so the value as an additional translation should be processed when creating it.

I must admit that I feel in a dead end. Could someone please share some knowledge on that matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [KnpDoctrineBehavious Bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable). It makes is very simple to translate any property of your entity:

```
class BlogPost
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    // anything that should not be translated
    // follows in this class
}
```

And add a translation entity:

```
class BlogPostTranslation
{
    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128)
     */
    private $slug;

    // ...
}
```

Now you can acces any translation like this:

```
$blogPost->getSlug(); // default language slug
$blogPost->translate('en')->getSlug(); // English slug
$blogPost->translate('fr')->getSlug(); // French slug
```

Don't forget to call `$entity->mergeNewTranslations();` after `$em->persist($entity);` to update the translation table.

#### Edit:

Note that the **DoctrineBehaviours Bundle** also supports a way better `Sluggable`. Use it like it's shown in [their documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#sluggable).

Comment: I will take a look at it and come back to you tomorrow ! Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Alright so I've tried using DoctrineBehaviours Bundle and it's indeed, pretty nice. However, I can't get the translate behaviour to work! I keep getting a weird error. It's looking for an Entity that doesn't exist. The message is : target-entity MyProject\MyBundle\Enti cannot be found in MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\BlogPost#translatable. Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a typo to me. Did you register the [Listeners](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#listeners)?

Comment: Yes listeners is registered. Most of the code is straight copy/paste from doc. Hmm

Comment: Just to provide more information, I simply imported the folder (copy/paste) in config.yml. I didn't do the doctrine2 way.

Comment: That is the correct way. Does the error message really say **MyProject\MyBundle\Enti cannot be found**?

Comment: Yes, using the log I went in doctrine and var_dump() the data. The "TargetEntity" is really looking for a folder \Enti. I tried using sluggable and it works perfectly. It's only when I try to translate it that the bug happen. I'm thinking about submiting a ticket on github.

Comment: Did you add the `@ORM\Entity` annotation to your translation entity? Is the database schema up-to-date? Could you add the new entities to your original question or create a new one?

Comment: Ok, I will close this one as this is for another subject. Thanks for the help I will post in the comment the link to the new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867913/translation-behaviour-is-looking-for-enti-folder